Horror movie which takes place in an old house with a girl with powers.
So, I saw this movie, like 4 (or more) years ago. The action took place in an old house. The main character is a girl (around 25 years old) who has the power to see the dead people, demons and so on. She inherited this power from her mother or grandmother (I can't remember). There are a lot of jump scares in that movie. I remember there were a lot of dead people in that house, especially in the basement, and most of them weren't evil, but they were controlled by a very powerful demon, I think.
I remember a scene in which the girl fell through a floor in the basement and a lot of dead people jumped on her, covering the girl, and her mother or grandmother always said to "Let them in" and she did in that moment and all of them disappeared.
I really want to see this movie again, please help me. :)

Sounds like a good movie.
